# Использование устаревшего класса TabActivity

Tags: xml, android, java

Решил разобраться с данным сабжем, нашел два туториала:

- [hello tabwidget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)
- [FragmentTabsPager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html)

Так как меня интересует Android 3.2, действовал по 1-му туториалу, все сделал, как там написано, однако эклипс про `TabActivity` говорит, что это уже устаревший класс и предлагает перед классом дописать строку

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation"),
```

Что, собственно, я и сделал, после чего в строке

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity
```

слово `TabActivity` стало красным и зачеркнутым, то же самое в импортах. Собственно, вопрос: в какую сторону копать, чтобы эта краснота пропала?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен тут - [Android Compatibility: Working with Fragments](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/).

Answer (score 0):

[Tab Layout на Android часть первая](http://dajver.blogspot.com/2011/12/tab-layout-android.html), а дальше по накатаной, все заработает